# Maven MultiWAR project: How to deploy them all from root project?

Tags: maven, tomcat, tomcat7, maven-3, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using multimodule Maven project. Some modules are simply JARs but some of them are WARs (sometimes WAR is submodule of other submodule).

I those WAR modules I'm using tomcat plugin. For example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>my_local_tomcat</server>
                <path>/registration</path>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now I must go to the root, then execute `mvn clean install`, then go into submodules containing WARs and execute `mvn tomcat:redeploy` for each one.

Can it be done from the root module to force `Maven` to find WARs and redeploy them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each module you want to deploy, add a tomcat-deploy profile

```
  <profiles>
<profile>
  <id>tomcat-deploy</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <server>my_local_tomcat</server>
          <path>/registration</path>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>deploy-war</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy-only</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Now run: mvn install -Ptomcat-deploy

Comment: Nice idea to do this like that! I will check this at home. Can it be used with redeploy goal with ignoring unsuccessfull undeploying?

Comment: uhm currently nope in case of IOException (remote tomcat not available etc..) that will fail. Maybe you can create a jira to have a parameter like ignoreFailure ?